# Agrupar counts de un case when

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, count, inner

como están?

Estoy teniendo un problema que no se como resolver.
Por un lado tengo una tabla de comercios (ID, nombre, dirección, categoría)
Por otro lado, tengo una tabla de pedidos repartidos (ID pedido, fecha expedido, fecha entregado, pais, ciudad, ID comercio, usuario, dirección pedido, costo, iva, estado)

Lo que estaría precisando, es contar la cantidad de comercios agrupados por CATEGORIA que tienen como minimo (en sumatoria) pedidos por $1000 de un determinado pais en un determinado año y un determinado mes.

Lo que me ocurre es que consigo la cantidad de comercios pero 1 fila por comercio, no agrupados por categoria, les dejo uno de los tantos querys que fui haciendo pero no logro agruparlos:

```
select count(distinct comercio_id) as "Cantidad de comercios",
 
sum(case when category = 'A' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria A",
sum(case when category = 'B' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria B",
sum(case when category = 'C' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria C",
sum(case when category = 'D' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria D"
from pedidos inner join comercios on comercios.id = pedidos.comercio_id
where pais = 'Chile' and estado = 'CONFIRMED' and month(order_date) = 4 and year(order_date) = 2017
group by categoria, comercio_id
having sum(round(order_amount, 2)) >= 1000;
```

Esta consulta me muestras varios unos "1" en la cantidad de restaurants y en la categoria me muestra la cantidad de pedidos agrupados, me deberia mostrar = Categoria A = 44, Categoria B = 36, etc.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas quitar las columnas de categoria y comercio del `GROUP BY` puesto que eso está haciendo que te muestre una fila por comercio y categoría.

```
select count(distinct comercio_id) as "Cantidad de comercios",
    sum(case when category = 'A' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria A",
    sum(case when category = 'B' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria B",
    sum(case when category = 'C' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria C",
    sum(case when category = 'D' then 1 else null end) as "Categoria D"
from pedidos inner join comercios on comercios.id = pedidos.comercio_id
where pais = 'Chile' and estado = 'CONFIRMED' and month(order_date) = 4 and year(order_date) = 2017
having sum(round(order_amount, 2)) >= 1000;
```

Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de que regrese el resultado esperado puesto que estás usando un distinct para la cantidad de comercios. Es probable que necesites algo así:

```
select count(distinct comercio_id) as "Cantidad de comercios",
    count(distinct case when category = 'A' then comercio_id else null end) as "Categoria A",
    count(distinct case when category = 'B' then comercio_id else null end) as "Categoria B",
    count(distinct case when category = 'C' then comercio_id else null end) as "Categoria C",
    count(distinct case when category = 'D' then comercio_id else null end) as "Categoria D"
from pedidos inner join comercios on comercios.id = pedidos.comercio_id
where pais = 'Chile' and estado = 'CONFIRMED' and month(order_date) = 4 and year(order_date) = 2017
having sum(round(order_amount, 2)) >= 1000;
```

Comment: Hola Luis, como estas?. Lo resolvi entrando primero por categoria y un exists en las ordenes, para luego agrupar por categoria fuera del exists.